# Differences of pairs of powers of integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm interested in equations of the form $n = x^a - y^b$, with integers $x, a, y, b, n$, and $a,b > 1$, for different values of $n$. For example:

$1 = 3^2 - 2^3$
$2 = 3^3 - 5^2$
$3 = 2^7 - 5^3$
$4 = 2^3 - 2^2$
$5 = 3^2 - 2^2$

So far, my rather primitive Python program has not found any such equation for $n = 6$. It seems likely that for any given integer, there are two powers of integers out there that differ by that integer. Has this been proven to be true or false?

Comment: Writing this as
$n + y^b = x^a$,
the [abc conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) implies there are only finitely many solutions $(x,y,a,b,n)$ with $x^{a} > (nxy)^{1 - \epsilon}$.

Answer (score 4):

Pillai's Diophantine equation is given by
$$
n=a^x-b^y
$$
for integers $a,b,x,y,n$. This is a classical topic with many results and several conjectures. A. Herschfeld showed that
if $n$  is an integer with sufficiently large $|n|$, then the equation
$$
2^x − 3^y = n
$$
has at most one solution $(x, y)$ in positive integers $x$ and $y$. For $|n|\le 10$ he showed that only for $n=-1,1,-5,5,-7,7$ there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably false in general, but just because [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A076427) states 6 has no such solutions. It's unclear to me if that's actually been proven or just that no solutions have been found after a large search, but I suspect the former. In any case, you should search for material related to Pillai's conjecture.